# PostgreSQL: View/Table Creation/Replace/Modification Date?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to see when a view was inserted/modified in Postgres.

I checked ***pg_views*** / ***pg_tables***, but both seem to lack any sort of date information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such information available.

Comment: I would have thought there would be a system table that logs those kind of events